# Run test setup only once

Tags: groovy, spock

Given a spock test below, the `setup` block runs once for each data element in `where` block. Can I make it run only once?

```
setup:
def x = 1

when:
x++

then:
x == y

where:
y << [2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: Does initialisng `x` in a separate `def setup() {}          // run before every feature method` method get you where you want to be?

Comment: @tim_yates It doesn't. When _where_ block is used every run for each y value will be executed as separate feature method. Thus x going to be reinitialized as well.

Answer (score 2):

Just use @Shared annotation and declare *x* as class field. The value is going to be reused between feature method executions (between multiple feature methods either).

```
class SomeSpockSpec extends Specification {

    @Shared def x = 1

    def 'x going to be incremented'() {
            when:
            x++

            then:
            x == y

            where:
            y << [2, 3, 4]
    }
}
```

Comment: If initializing a shared variable requires more code than a simple assignment statement, you can create a setupSpec() method. That will be executed once before any tests in the spec run.

Comment: @AlexBlakemore is right. Moreover __setupSpec()__ method works well with fields annotated as __@Shared__.

Comment: That isn't an ideal solution especially in cases where there are more tests which don't use the variable x.